# Maven exception thrown while running the program

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I am trying to run the program, I am getting Maven exception, something to do with the version. Can anyone please help with how to configure the version here?

[image]

pom.xml file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.imalittletester</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoMaven1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>DemoMaven1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>5</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am trying to run a Java program.

Comment: The error tells you what you need to do. Read it again carefully.

Comment: But I am not able to find the 1.5 version in the project sdk dropdown, sorry I am new so don't know much about it.

Comment: Upgrade language version in maven file
See https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-versionsection 2.1  - Does it look familiar?

Comment: You JDK 20 tells you that you can't compile targeted to JDK 5 (which is by the way ancient old) ... you have to use more recent versions means you should use `<maven.compiler.release>20</maven.compiler.release>` or maybe something like `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` or alike...

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to remove

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>5</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

And try something like:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>20</java.version>
</properties>
```

Little more explanations:
`java.version` is setting which java you version would like to use. But there are two things to consider:

- Which JDK(s) or JVM(s) you have installed on your computer
- Which one of them is linked to your project.

Now In `Intellij` (your IDE) you can go to root project folder then right click and go to the `Open Module Settings`. Then in the popup window on the left side you will see `Project` click on it. You will see `SDK` and `Language Level` options. They should be the same as `java.version`. You should select also the corresponding version. In the `SDK` you can select the path to particular `JDK` - `Java Development Kit` or `JVM` - `Java Virtual Machine`.

Good luck to all

Reply: -
[image]

[image]

Are you talking about this?
`In this window please look at the left side menu on the top there is Project (just below Project Settigs). Click on this`

What do you mean by same as java.version?
`When you click on Project you will see. Please read one more time my previous answer`

I have currently jdk 20. Please let me know what changes you need over here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install jdk 1.8 that is the most using jdk.

You are trying to run this program with java 1.5, that is deprecated in most of the IDEs.